# curreent login user record updation Error In PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

i want that when ever a login user want they can change their record(address,etc). for such purpose i make a autofill form for the current login user.Now the Problem is that the data won,t be updated..

My Form Code IS........

```
<?php session_start();
include 'conn.php';
include '../includes/layouts/header.php';
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    header("location:signin.php");
}
$sql="SELECT * FROM signup";
$qry=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($qry);
?>

    <div id="main">
        <div id="navigation">
        &nbsp;
        </div>
        <div id="page">
            <h2>Login Section</h2>
            <p>Welcome to LMS</p>

            <form method="post" action="update.php">
                <div class="reg_section">
                    <h3>Your Personal Information</h3>

                    <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $rows[1];?>" placeholder="First Name"><br>
                    <input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php echo $rows[2];?>" placeholder="Last Name"><br>
                    <input type="text" name="uname" value="<?php echo $rows[3];?>" placeholder="Desired Username"><br>
                    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $rows[4];?>" placeholder="Email"><br>
                    <input type="text" name="department" value="<?php echo $rows[5];?>" placeholder="Department"><br>
                    <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $rows[6];?>" placeholder="Id #"/><br>
                    <input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $rows[7];?>" placeholder="Phone #"/><br>

                </div>
                <div class="reg_section">
                    <h3>Your Password</h3>
                    <input type="password" name="pass" value="<?php echo $rows[8];?>" placeholder="Your Password"><br>
                    <input type="password" name="cpass" value="<?php echo $rows[8];?>" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                </div>
                <div class="reg_section">
                    <h3>Your Address</h3>
                    <input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo $rows[9];?>" placeholder="Address">
                </div>
                <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Info"></p>

            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
```

My PHP CODE IS..........

```
<?php session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    $user=$_POST['uname'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $depart=$_POST['department'];
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];
    $address=$_POST['address'];

    $qry="UPDATE  signup SET First_Name=$$fname,Last_Name=$$lname,Username=$$user,Email=$$email,Department=$$depart,Employe_Id=$$id,Phone=$$phone,Password=$$pass,Address=$$address WHERE Username=$$user";

    if(mysql_query($qry))
    {

        header('location:setting.php');
    }
}
?>
```

Can any one know that what is the error...

Comment: What are the _double_ dollar chars doing there (`$$`)?

Comment: A side note: your code is wide open to sql injection, that is a high security risk! You are using a deprecated database driver. Please switch to the more modern and more secure `mysqli` php extension and learn about the advantages of "prepared statements"!

Comment: Missing the selected user `SELECT * FROM signup` on your form so it will always get the wrong user instead of the logged in one unless there is only one user, double `$` and SQL Injection on your second code not to mention you're not using single quotes to define the extent of each variable which is most likely breaking the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this sql

```
$qry="UPDATE  signup 
      SET First_Name='$fname', Last_Name='$lname', Username='$user', Email='$email',Department='$depart', Employe_Id='$id', Phone='$phone', Password='$pass', Address='$address' 
      WHERE Username='$user' LIMIT 1 ";
```

Comment: it is reducing sql execution time when we know that there is exactly one record in the table.

Comment: That would depend on the indexes on that table, actually.

Comment: @arkascha indexes would make very little difference unless its a unique field and MySQL recognizes that and stop which I don't know if it does so I cant confirm it and if it does that it would be the similar effect of what LIMIT would do.

Comment: A unique key automatically results in an index. But whatever, performance really is _not_ the problem here.

Comment: @arkascha yes but what I am saying is that the LIMIT will make it stop once a record is found while not using LIMIT may not make it stop on a UNIQUE field unless MySQL knows it should stop which is what I am not sure of, that is what I was trying to say.

Comment: We all perfectly well understood that in the first place. As said: that certainly is _not_ of interest in this case.

Comment: @Prix i agreed with your comment. sql will stop when found the record unless to search whole table for single record.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my first comment above you have a problem in how you construct your query. You were using *double* dollar chars (`$$`) which does not make any sense. The result is that you run an empty query which explains why not record is updated.

As a *first* step alter your query like this:

```
$qry = "UPDATE signup SET 
         First_Name='$fname', Last_Name='$lname', Username='$user', 
         Email='$email', Department='$depart', Employe_Id='$id', 
         Phone='$phone', Password='$pass', Address='$address' 
        WHERE Username='$user'";
```

You do not implement any form of error handling, that is why you don't see the error you get from mysql. Please take a look at some tutorials about how to do that.

Also consider my second comment about preventing sql injections. At least, as some kind of "hot fix" you should use `mysql_real_ecape()` on all user input you integrate into your query. But as said, the only real solution is to switch to "prepared statements".

Comment: @webeno try your code with a space on any variable and u will know why.